# On-The-Fly DependencyProperties

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I have a class which calculates it's property on-the-fly, for example:

```
class CircleArea
{
    public double Radius { get; set; }
    public double Area
    {
        get
        {
            return Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

I make it an DependencyObject by doing:

```
class CircleArea:
    DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Radius", typeof(double), typeof(CircleArea));
    public double Radius
    {
        get { return (double)GetValue(RadiusProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(RadiusProperty, value);
            CoerceValue(AreaProperty);
        }
    }

    internal static readonly DependencyPropertyKey AreaPropertyKey =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Area", typeof(double), typeof(CircleArea), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN));
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AreaProperty = AreaPropertyKey.DependencyProperty;
    public double Area
    {
        get
        {
            return Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
        }
    }
}
```

And then I have 2 textboxes in XAML, one with TwoWay binding to Radius, another with OneWay binding to Area.

What should I do to make edits to the textbox for Radius update the textbox for Area?

Comment: I tried `CoerceValue(AreaProperty);` and `InvalidateProperty(AreaProperty);`, but none of them works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of ways you can do this.

- For simplicity, you can implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`, use a regular property for Area, and then trigger the event in the `OnDependencyPropertyChanged` for `RadiusProperty`.
- For more complexity, you'd set `AreaProperty` using the key privately whenever Radius changes. Your property would look like this.

  ```
  public static readonly DependencyProperty RadiusProperty = 
      DependencyProperty.Register(
          "Radius",  
          typeof(double), 
          typeof(CircleArea), 
          new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(0.0, OnRadiusChanged))


  private static void OnRadiusChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
       Area = Radius * Radius * Math.PI;
  }



  private static readonly DependencyPropertyKey AreaKey=
      DependencyProperty.RegisterReadOnly("Area", typeof(double)...
  public static readonly DependencyProperty AreaProperty = AreaKey.DependencyProperty;

  public Double Area
  {
      get
      {
          return (Double)GetValue(AreaProperty);
      }
      private set
      {
          SetValue(AreaKey, value);
      }
  }
  ```

You can still set a one way binding to `Area`.